# Java CRC32: not the same as CRC from C# 

Tags: java, crc

I have to compare files with java with a CRC32 code provided by a C# script. When I calculate the CRC32 with java.util.zip.CRC32 the result is completely different ...

My guess is that the polynom = 0x2033 of the C# script is not the same as used in zip.CRC32. Is it possible to set the polynom ? Or any ideas of a java-class for calculating a CRC32 where you can define your own polynom?

UPDATE: problem is not the polymnom. This is the same between C# and Java

This is my code, maybe something is wrong in the way I read the file?

```
package com.mine.digits.internal.contentupdater;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public class CRC 
{
    public static String doConvert32(File file)
    {
        byte[] bytes = readBytesFromFile(file); // readFromFile(file).getBytes();

        CRC32 x = new CRC32();
        x.update(bytes);

        return (Long.toHexString(x.getValue())).toUpperCase();
    }

    /** Read the contents of the given file. */
    private static byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            long length = file.length(); 
            if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) { 
                // File is too large 
            } 

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length]; 
            int offset = 0; 
            int numRead = 0; 
            while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0)
            { 
                offset += numRead; 
            } 

            // Ensure all the bytes have been read in 
            if (offset < bytes.length) { 
                System.out.println("Could not completely read file " + file.getName()); 
            } 

            // Close the input stream and return bytes 
            is.close(); 

            return bytes;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException " + file.getName()); 

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: The alternatives are: a) you're not using the API correctly from Java, C# or both; b) the C# code you're using is buggy. Without seeing your code or the C# code you're using, it's hard to say. A pair of short but complete programs with a small amount of test data would really help.

Comment: FYI: [It's spelled "Java", not "JAVA".](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2271/241)

Comment: Your Java code looks OK, perhaps there is something wrong on the C# side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by copying the code from C# and convert it to a Java-class...

So now both use the same code, only had to do some minor changes for unsigned <> signed bytes differences.

Answer (score 3):

The standard (IEEE) CRC32 polynomial is **0x04C11DB7** which corresponds to:

```
x^32 + x^26 + x^23 + x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 +
x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
```

This is what java.util.zip.CRC32 uses. Don't know about the C# script you mention...

You can find this code snippet useful:

- http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/51data/CRC32.java.html

Answer (score 1):

CRC-32 is a specific CRC variant according to IEEE 802.3 and is using the polynom 0x04C11DB7. If your C# library is using the polynom 0x2033, it is /not/ an implementation of CRC-32.

If you need Java code to calculate arbitrary CRC variants, googling "java crc" will give you several examples.

Comment: Ok, I investigated this a bit further, and found out the C# is actually using 0x04C11DB7 so this is the same for the java class. Problem must be somewhere else why my crc isn't the same on C# and JAVA...

Comment: For CRCs, also the endiannes matters. CRCs do not process bytes; instead they operate on streams of bits. Hence if you have issues with bit ordering within bytes or byte orderings within words, you won't get the same result.

Comment: @Schedler: Most CRC algorithm implementations work on one byte at a time, so there should be no byte ordering issues. And if there are, that's a bug in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1    + x    + x^2  + x^4  + x^5  + x^7  + x^8  + x^10 + x^11 + x^12 + x^16 + x^22 + x^23 + x^26 
(0x04C11DB7)
Java uses the above polynomial for CRC 32 calculation and is different from IEEE 802.3 standard which has a 32 bit power of x in addition.

Comment: The x^32 part is silently added.