# Is there any difference in calculating CRC32 checksum in C# and Java?

Tags: c#, java, crc32

I have to calculate CRC32 checksum for a string in C# and send it to an external application.

On the other end they will calculate it using Java.

But my checksum does not match on the their end.

e.g. CRC32 checksum of the following string
43HLV109520DAP10072la19z6

is 1269993351 on their end.

And 2947932745 at my end using C#

Please tell me what's going wrong in my code.

I am using this 0xffffffff default seed and following crc table

```
readonly static uint[] CRCTable = new uint[] {
            0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA, 0x076DC419,
            0x706AF48F, 0xE963A535, 0x9E6495A3, 0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4,
            0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988, 0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD, 0xE7B82D07,
            0x90BF1D91, 0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2, 0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE,
            0x1ADAD47D, 0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7, 0x136C9856,
            0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC, 0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9,
            0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5, 0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4,
            0xA2677172, 0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B,
            0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C, 0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940, 0x32D86CE3,
            0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59, 0x26D930AC, 0x51DE003A,
            0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116, 0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423, 0xCFBA9599,
            0xB8BDA50F, 0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924,
            0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB, 0xB6662D3D, 0x76DC4190,
            0x01DB7106, 0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A, 0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F,
            0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433, 0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E,
            0xE10E9818, 0x7F6A0DBB, 0x086D3D2D, 0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01,
            0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E, 0x6C0695ED,
            0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457, 0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950,
            0x8BBEB8EA, 0xFCB9887C, 0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3,
            0xFBD44C65, 0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE, 0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2,
            0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7, 0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB, 0x4369E96A,
            0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0, 0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5,
            0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9, 0x5005713C, 0x270241AA, 0xBE0B1010,
            0xC90C2086, 0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409, 0xCE61E49F,
            0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4, 0x59B33D17,
            0x2EB40D81, 0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD, 0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6,
            0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A, 0xEAD54739, 0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615,
            0x73DC1683, 0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84, 0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8,
            0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1, 0xF00F9344,
            0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268, 0x6906C2FE, 0xF762575D, 0x806567CB,
            0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7, 0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0, 0x10DA7A5A,
            0x67DD4ACC, 0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5,
            0xD6D6A3E8, 0xA1D1937E, 0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252, 0xD1BB67F1,
            0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B, 0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C,
            0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60, 0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55, 0x316E8EEF,
            0x4669BE79, 0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236,
            0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703, 0x220216B9, 0x5505262F, 0xC5BA3BBE,
            0xB2BD0B28, 0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04, 0xC2D7FFA7, 0xB5D0CF31,
            0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D, 0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C,
            0x026D930A, 0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
            0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE, 0x0CB61B38, 0x92D28E9B,
            0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21, 0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242,
            0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E, 0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1,
            0x18B74777, 0x88085AE6, 0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C,
            0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69, 0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45, 0xA00AE278,
            0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2, 0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7,
            0x4969474D, 0x3E6E77DB, 0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC, 0x40DF0B66,
            0x37D83BF0, 0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5, 0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9,
            0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6, 0xBAD03605,
            0xCDD70693, 0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF, 0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8,
            0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94, 0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B,
            0x2D02EF8D
        };
```

Comment: Have you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344190/java-crc32-not-the-same-as-crc-from-c-sharp

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your code. Maybe you are ending up with Strings with different underlying binary representations or character encodings, so they look the same but checksum differently.

Comment: How do you compute? With witch library or self-made functions? Algorithm matters!

Comment: CRC is calculated over a sequence of bytes and not over a string. If you use a different encoding to transform a string to a sequence of bytes the result will be different. So please post your encoding related code.

Comment: @StefanP. Yeah, I have looked this code. But didn't get my answer.

Comment: @Dims I have inherited HashAlgorithm class of C#

Comment: @CodesInChaos I used ASCII encoding to generate bytes-

Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
   crc32.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgText));

Comment: Post sufficient code to answer the question.

Comment: I believe the bug in in the Java code, not the C# code.

Comment: It depends first of all on whether both languages are using the same CRC polynomial and initial value. Have you investigated that?  The Java CRC32 calculation is documented. What parameters is your home-grown C# code using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have calculated CRC32 with Java and got the same you got in C#. I.e. `CRC32(43HLV109520DAP10072la19z6)=2947932745`. This means that either they have a bug in java, or you have a bug during transmission.

Code follows.

I suggest you try to send simple data to java application, like zeros or ones, and try to deduce how do they compute CRC.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();

    String data = "43HLV109520DAP10072la19z6";

    String[] cs = new String[] {"utf8" /*, "cp1252", "cp866" */};
    byte[] array;
    byte b;

    for(int i=0; i<cs.length; ++i) {

        array = data.getBytes(Charset.forName(cs[i]));

        crc32.reset();
        crc32.update(array);

        System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d", cs[i], crc32.getValue()));

        /*
        for(int j=0; j<array.length/2; j++) {
            b = array[i];
            array[i] = array[array.length-1-i];
            array[array.length-1-i] = b;
        }
        */

        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j+=2) {
            b = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+2];
            array[i+1] = b;
        }

        crc32.reset();
        crc32.update(array);

        System.out.println(String.format("of modified: %d", crc32.getValue()));
    }




}
```

**UPDATE**

Endiannes reverse also not help

```
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j+=4) {

            b = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+3];
            array[i+3] = b;


            b = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = array[i+2];
            array[i+2] = b;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I will do according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

CRC32 is calculated over a sequence of bytes and not over a string. So to calculate CRC32 you need to transform the string into bytes first. If you use a different encoding to transform a string to a sequence of bytes the result will be different.

Thus you need to use the same encoding on both sides. I recommend using UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I used UTF-8 but didn't get the required result.
Can you see my example and check why I am unable to get required checksum?

Comment: I do not have Java code
but I know they are using java.util.zip.CRC32 java library.
CRC32  crc  = new CRC32 ();
crc.update (msgText.getBytes ()); 
crc = crc.getValue();

Comment: And I referring this C# code-

[link](http://tomkaminski.com/crc32-hashalgorithm-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into any detail, the problem can be related to Java's lack of unsigned integer types. The problem could happen at the `int` level, but also at the `byte` level. This is one avenue of investigation.

Comment: I do not have Java code but I know they are using java.util.zip.CRC32 java library. CRC32  crc  = new CRC32 (); crc.update (msgText.getBytes ()); crc = crc.getValue(); 
And I referring this C# code-  [link](http://tomkaminski.com/crc32-hashalgorithm-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

CRC is calculated over a sequence of bytes and not over a string.
Whichever CRC in java looks different due unavailability of Unsigned int in java.

Convert calculated Int CRC into Hex String and take last 2 Bytes (length 4)

That is your actual CRC unsigned Int.

```
String hexCrc = Integer.toHexString(crcCalculated);
hexCrc = hexCrc.substring(hexCrc.length()-4);
```

compare hex CRC of c# and Java both should be same.